Was the ' turn' of washing of Peter's feet by Jesus pre-determined?
We read of the Washing of Feet of the disciples by Jesus in Jn 13:5-6:

He poured water into the washbasin and began to wash the disciples’ feet and to dry them with the towel he had wrapped around himself.
Then he came to Simon Peter. Peter said to him, “Lord, are you going to wash my feet?”

Peter is understood to be the seniormost disciple by age, and would subsequently be declared as the Rock on which Jesus would build his Church. In ceremonies, the seniormost persons are give  certain previleges. But, here we see Jesus washing Peter's feet after the turn of at least a few other disciples if not all. My question is : was it a pre-determined  action from Jesus' side meant  to convey a message ?

If I then, your Lord and Teacher, have washed your feet, you also ought to wash one another’s feet. 15 For I have given you an example, that you also should do just as I have done to you.  (John 13:14–15, ESV)

Peter, and the other disciples, came to realize that Jesus’ act of washing their feet was a demonstration of Jesus' love and a call to a life of service. Jesus gave them a practical, on the job lesson in humility and servant leadership. He was showing that true greatness in the kingdom of God is not found in status or authority, but in serving others. Jesus modeled this by taking on the role of a servant, despite being their Lord and Teacher.
Furthermore, Peter might have understood that Jesus’ actions pointed to a spiritual cleansing. Just as He washed their feet, Jesus would cleanse them from sin through His sacrifice on the cross.
That being said:
The Gospel of John does not provide specific details about the order in which Jesus washed the disciples’ feet or why Peter did not go first.
However, there are at least two possible reasons:

By not starting with Peter, despite his seniority, Jesus could have been giving the lesson of humility and service to all, showing that rank and status do not dictate one’s worthiness of service.

It is said of Jesus:

John 13:11 - For He knew who would betray Him; therefore He said, “You
are not all clean.”


Jesus, with divine foreknowledge, may have chosen the sequence to facilitate the unfolding of events as they were meant to happen, including the important dialogue with Peter that ensued.

